# call combobox gotfocus event in inside the function

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i am working on windows form application,i have two combo box.inside the function i have to check which combobox i have focuse.depend on that i have to do some operation

i have done coding in combox focus event like this

```
Private Sub cmbfrmwarehouse_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbfrmwarehouse.GotFocus


        Dim currencombobox As ComboBox = sender

    If currencombobox.Equals(cmbfrmwarehouse) Then
        MessageBox.Show("it's in two")
    ElseIf currencombobox.Equals(cmbTowarehouse) Then
        MessageBox.Show("it's in three")
    End If
    End Sub
```

but i am not able to call this event in inside the function.how i can achieve this.Please help

Comment: What do you mean you are "not able to call this event in inside the function"? What event are you calling? Where? Which function?

Comment: sir i have a function like this sub loaddetaisl() ,i am calling comboxfocus event like this: cmbfrmwarehouse_GotFocus(sender,e). but showing error.or else,is there any way to do inside the my function

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Side-Note:Message.Box showing in `GotFocus` event  leads continuous looping

Answer (score 2):

They have to share the same event handler. The `sender` object is the combobox in question.

```
Private Sub cmbfrmwarehouse_GotFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                            Handles cmbfrmwarehouse.GotFocus, cmbTowarehouse.GotFocus
 Dim currencombobox As ComboBox = sender
 If currencombobox.Equals(cmbfrmwarehouse) Then
    MessageBox.Show("it's in two")
 ElseIf currencombobox.Equals(cmbTowarehouse) Then
    MessageBox.Show("it's in three")
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No I added the other combobox to the event handler - look closely.

Comment: what is the use of that?

Comment: If they both use the same event handler you can check to see which one got focus with your code inside. If you only have one combobox wire to that even,t there is no reason for checking which sender object it is - cause it will always be the one you wired to the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call an event. you can either raise the event (in this case, by setting the focus on the correct combo box) or call it's handler:

**To raise this event** use the Focus() method of the relevant combo box:

```
cmbfrmwarehouse.Focus() '' or cmbTowarehouse.Focus()
```

However, this will only execute the event handler for `cmbfrmwarehouse` unless you will also use [OneFindeDay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193124/3094533) and have both combo boxes share the same event handler for the GotFocus event.

**The other way** is to call the event handler simply call it like you would any other method:

```
 cmbfrmwarehouse_GotFocus(cmbfrmwarehouse, EventArgs.Empty)
 '' or 
 cmbfrmwarehouse_GotFocus(cmbTowarehouse, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Comment: sir i added my above code in focus event,then i called  cmbfrmwarehouse_GotFocus(cmbfrmwarehouse, EventArgs.Empty) this in my fucnction,but i am getting error

Comment: i resolved that error,but i want to know,i want to call this two events in my function

Comment: Again, events are not called, they are raised. the .Net framework is responsible of calling the event handler once it's hooked up to an event. However, you are free to call the event handler directly or raise the event by setting focus to the relevant combo box. Did you try my answer?